# How To Get The Local TIme In Models.DateTimeField() In Django?

Tags: python, django, datetime

I was trying to get the local time in the models section of my models.py file in Django. 
But this function returns the server time which is about 5 hours less than my local time, so, how do I get this correct?

```
date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go in your settings.py and make changes

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Karachi'    # Change it to your location

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 1):

On the settings.py, you set the timezone to your timezone.

e.g

```
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Manila'
```

You can check the list of time zones [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way that Django can display the time_zone according to the user?

Comment: Definitely! Your USE_TZ variable should be set to True. That would do the trick.

Comment: @Heisenberg I should add that localtime Enables or disables conversion of aware datetime objects to the current time zone in the contained block.

This tag has exactly the same effects as the USE_TZ setting as far as the template engine is concerned. It allows a more fine grained control of conversion.

To activate or deactivate conversion for a template block, use: ```{% load tz %}

{% localtime on %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}

{% localtime off %}
    {{ value }}
{% endlocaltime %}```